# Accepting "Sharing Location" browser popups through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, geolocation

I've Googled, searched SO, and looked at the Selenium Javadocs but haven't found an answer to this question.

**Is there any way, using Selenium WebDriver, to accept those "Share Location" popups that get displayed by browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) when a website is trying to track your location?**

Also, I'm writing up my Selenium code in Java and using the Selenium Client Drivers.

I've tried running the Selenium IDE (the Firefox add-on) and recording me accepting the "Share Location" popup that Firefox popsup but nothing gets recorded in the Selenium IDE.

Comment: Its for testing a feature of the website that allows the user to enable location tracking.

Answer (score 1):

If the popup is part of the browser then the answer is no.  If you want to interact with something displayed in a second window ( not part of the browser) then yes. There should be a .switch_to method.

Although if you can have this page remember your settings you can load a profile when you create a new instance of the browser.

In windows you can create a profile in firefox by going to the start menu and typing "firefox.exe -p" here you can create a new profile where you you would have a "remember me check box" checked.

As far as loading a profile in Java + Selenium I'm not sure how you would do this.  I use Ruby + Selenium and this is how I do it.

```
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => "MyProfile"
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me more about loading profiles? Is this something I can Google easily?? I think loading profiles may be the answer since the testing won't be very useful if I can't "accept" location tracking programmatically through Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to this in firefox but still working on chrome. The below code should help and fetch your exact location on maps:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
    myprofile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);
    myprofile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);
    myprofile.setPreference("geo.wifi.uri", "https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,myprofile);
```

After this just pass the FirefoxProfile instance in the driver method just as below(for the above code):

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

That should be fine, write all the other stuff you want and execute!!